# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument " " not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

I am new to JPA working with Netbeans and EclipseLink and I have created an entity Manager as well as a PK class, and a main class.

When I try to use the pre-generated names from Netbeans

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Company.findUser", query = "SELECT c FROM Company c WHERE c.companyPK.user = :user")
@NamedQuery(name = "Company.findPass", query = "SELECT c FROM Company c WHERE c.password = :password")
```

I am greeted with the error above

but

```
    @NamedQuery(name = "Company.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Company c")
```

works and shows me everything......

Company:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Company")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Company.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Company c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Company.findUser", query = "SELECT c FROM Company c WHERE c.companyPK.user = :user"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Company.findPass", query = "SELECT c FROM Company c WHERE c.password = :password")})
public class Company implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected CompanyPK companyPK;
    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String password;
```

CompanyPK:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "User")
private String user;
```

AdminControl:

AdminControl:

```
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UploaderPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Company c = new Company(new CompanyPK(userF.getText()),pass.getText());
    em.persist(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();


       // TypedQuery<Company> query = em.createNamedQuery("Company.findUser", Company.class);
    Query q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Company c WHERE c.companyPK.user = :user");
    System.out.println(q1.getSingleResult());
```

The above code is an error, but if I use Company.find all/"SELECT c From Company c" I will get all of the data in my db.

I know the data is also stored since I query my DB with netbeans each time to see the results.

What is interesting is that if I put the same data twice, i.e., user = a 2x I will get an error saying that the primary key is duplicated blah blah.

So I know it can read it, but why am I getting an error when it's not a duplicate?

Full error:

```
 [EL Info]: 2014-09-26 19:18:10.995--ServerSession(1090396648)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: connection: 2014-09-26 19:18:14.249--ServerSession(1090396648)--file:/C:/Users/Konrad/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FB-Style-Page-Slide-Menu/Uploader/build/classes/_UploaderPU login successful
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument user not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.processParameters(QueryImpl.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:400)
    at uploader.AdminControl$1.handle(AdminControl.java:100)
    at uploader.AdminControl$1.handle(AdminControl.java:76)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog$7.handle(Dialog.java:1095)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog$7.handle(Dialog.java:1093)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:129)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:513)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:519)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:462)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.HeavyweightDialog$1.showAndWait(HeavyweightDialog.java:135)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.HeavyweightDialog.show(HeavyweightDialog.java:278)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:321)
    at uploader.AdminControl.addUser(AdminControl.java:209)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1759)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1274370218.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line 100 of `AdminResult`, you are executing one of the named queries (your post does not show which, but it is probably `Company.findUser`). This query has a parameter `:user` in the JPQL. If `q` is your query, you need to do

```
q.setParameter("user", someValue);
```

to assign a value to that parameter at query execution time.

As an aside, it may be better to query for user and password in one query and making sure this returns exactly one hit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I posted this before I passed out, I knew I would forget something, I have updated the end with "AdminControl"


Basically what this is doing is creating a new user account; however from what your last sentence seems to suggest you're talking about a single query for user login/authentication or...?

Basically I would be storing about 3-4 pieces of information into the db with this new acc creation, so should I query them all together?

Thank you.  I will try the set parameter, but I thought that


begin();
        em.persist(c);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
is what works.

Comment: This ended up working, thank you.  I was originally looking at http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/start/crud

but found http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter so I will check this out more, thanks again.